# dictionary from a single list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a user defined list(so it is not static.For example's sake let's say the user entered the following elements in the list)

`['sam', '25', 'matt', '30', 'jack', '27']`

Is it possible to convert it into dictionary with name as key and age as value?

Comment: So you want something like `[{'name': 'sam', 'age': 25}, {'name': 'matt', 'age': 30}, ...]`?

Comment: If it's always in pairs, then `dict(zip(data[::2], data[1::2]))` ?

Comment: @fedorqui yes.I want something like that

Comment: @klaptor then you should show your attempts, please [edit] to explain properly your required output (for example witht the format I provided) and what you tried :)

Comment: @klaptor then the solution is in Jon Clements comment - but you actually have a design issue in the way the data are collected, they should already be grouped together (as a dict or as a list of `(name, age)` tuples) instead of being dumped that way in a list. A list is supposed to be homogenous - items in the list should not have a different meaning depending on their position in the list. IOW, you'd better fix the issue at the source.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I'm new to python but I understand now where I made mistake.Thanks for the explaintaion!

Comment: @klaptor note that this issue is nothing python-specific, it'a about proper data structure design whatever the language.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `zip` to create `tuples` of key-value pairs and then type-cast these to `dict` as:

```
>>> my_list = ['sam', '25', 'matt', '30', 'jack', '27']

>>> dict(zip(my_list[::2], my_list[1::2]))
{'matt': '30', 'jack': '27', 'sam': '25'}
```

Or you may use a *dictionary comprehension* with `range` as:

```
>>> {my_list[i]: my_list[i+1] for i in range(0, len(my_list), 2)}
{'matt': '30', 'jack': '27', 'sam': '25'}
```

---

Performance comparison of both the solutions:

```
# Using `zip`
mquadri$ python -m timeit -s "my_list = ['sam', '25', 'matt', '30', 'jack', '27']" "{my_list[i]: my_list[i+1] for i in range(0, len(my_list), 2)}"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.872 usec per loop

# Using "dictionary comprehension"
mquadri$ python -m timeit -s "my_list = ['sam', '25', 'matt', '30', 'jack', '27']" "dict(zip(my_list[::2], my_list[1::2]))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.53 usec per loop
```

Comment: Use `zip()` instead

Answer (score 0):

Dict constructor accepts an iterable of (key, value) tuples. So, you just have to iterate over the list two at a time

```
def two_at_time(iterable):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * 2
    return zip(*args)

lst = ['a', 5, 'b', 6]

my_dict = dict(two_at_time(lst))
```

Comment: For a list, `zip(data[::2], data[1::2])` works just as well and is quite simpler

Answer (score 0):

result_dict={}

```
for i in range(0,len(a),2):
       result_dict[a[i]]=a[i+1]
```

output :

```
 {'sam': '25', 'matt': '30', 'jack': '27'}
```